# std::future.get() Multiple Calls (from Different Threads)

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, future

Once `std::future.get()` is called, it becomes invalid, as a call to `future.valid()` will confirm. The following code piece will fail at run-time with the error [g++ 4.7.0]:

```
  terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::future_error'
  what():  No associated state
```

I'm trying to encode a dependency of **th1** and **th2** both waiting on completion of **th0**.

The problem is that `std::future.get()` cannot be called from 2 threads.

I can think of a couple of fixes involving `condition_variable`, or communicating results through a queue, etc.

- What is the best/most efficient fix?
- Just use a `condition_variable` and `notify_all()`?

Thanks.

```
 template<typename R>
 class scheduler
 {
  public:
    typedef R ret_type;
    typedef std::function<R()> fun_type;
    typedef std::promise<ret_type> prom_type;
    typedef std::future<ret_type> fut_type;

    // ...

  private:
    void init();
    ...
    std::vector<prom_type> prom;
    std::vector<fut_type> fut;
    ...

  };


template<typename R>
scheduler<R>::init()
{
  // ...

  // set fut[i] = prom[i].get_future(), for each i

  fun_type f0 = myFun0;
  fun_type f1 = myFun1;
  fun_type f2 = myFun2;

  std::thread th0([this](fun_type f)
                 {
                   prom[0].set_value(f0());
                 },f0)

  std:thread th1([this](fun_type f, R fut_val)
                 {
                   prom[1].set_value(f1());
                 },f1,fut[0].get());
  std::thread th2([this](fun_type f, R fut_val)
                 {
                   prom[2].set_value(f2());
                 },f2,fut[0].get());

  // Join on threads : th0.join(), etc.
  }
```

Comment: `std::shared_future`?

Comment: Uh yeah that seems like what I want. I'll try...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should consider using [`shared_future`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_future) for this.

> The class template std::shared_future provides a mechanism to access the result of asynchronous operations, similar to std::future, except that multiple threads are allowed to wait for the same shared state.... Access to the same shared state from multiple threads is safe if each thread does it through its own copy of a shared_future object.

Comment: Yup that just works - a one-line change to my typedef. I had overlooked this - thanks!

Comment: @charles no.  Each thread must have its own shared_future copy with the same shared state: the above code in OP with future replaced with shared future is not valid afaict